# Building Ruby 32-bit on CentOS 5

Tags: ruby, 32bit-64bit, centos5

I've been having trouble trying to ./configure && make && make install ruby 1.9.2 in CentOS 64-bit as a 32-bit package. No matter how I configure and build it, it always seems to come out as a 64-bit package.

I've tried running the ./configure command with the CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32" CXXFLAGS="-m32" and the —target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu option. That last option changed the architecture that showed up in the resulting ruby command, but it was still 64-bit.

I've also tried installing rvm and then installing ruby 1.9.2 with the flags they recommended in their troubleshooting [docs](http://beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/).

I'm also trying ./configure && make in a 32-bit installation of CentOS I have and then copying that over to my 64-bit install and then running make install. I have no idea if this will work.

I've been looking around the internet for help for well over a day and can't seem to find much on google. It seems that I'm not finding the magical combination of options to set when running ./configure && make && make install.

Let me know if you need any more information and I'd be happy to provide it. Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** Looked over my sources on the internet and reread [this](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/dbbb7739ab87433c/e6e3458e0a2f30a4?#e6e3458e0a2f30a4), specifically someone's instructions on how to compile Ruby as 32-bit, using the search command. I used yum to install setarch and then followed those directions - still no luck. Ruby's still compiling as 64-bit.

Comment: You may have a lot of trouble doing this unless all the supporting libraries Ruby requires are also 32-bit.

Comment: @tadman Is there a way to force gcc to error out if not all the libraries Ruby requires are 32-bit? I'm assuming that this is still in the build process.

Comment: Usually the linker will give up if it can't find the appropriate libraries, though the error message itself might seem to imply the library isn't present when really it's just the not type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed these libraries - http://www.linuxweblog.com/blogs/sandip/20080718/support-32-bit-development-libraries-64-bit-centos

Comment: Looked at your - the libstdc++-devel.i386 library wasn't installed. I installed it and redid ./configure && make && make install. The command 'file ruby' returns 'ruby: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped'. So, it's still 64-bit. : (

Comment: did you run configure with the m32 option ?

Comment: I was running it with the CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32" CXXFLAGS="-m32" options. Should I be doing it differently?

Comment: Can you pastebin the output of make ? It might help figure out if the -m32 option is being correctly passed to the compiler and linker as well as see what libraries it is linking against.

Comment: I ran 'CFLAGS='-m32' LDFLAGS='-m32' ./configure --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu' and then 'make' and my output is at http://pastebin.com/2rgEVYKA. If it helps, I noticed in the Makefile that there's nothing listed in the CFLAGS setting.

Comment: try running a make clean before you do a make. It seems like a lot of the targets have already been built on previous runs and the few that were made, I didn't see the -m32 flag being passed to either gcc or the linker.

Comment: Ran 'make clean' and then the previous statements - ruby was still 64-bit. Here's the output of make: http://pastebin.com/wNS8F9S0

Comment: Yes you can see the problem in the make log. The -m32 switch is not being passed into gcc at all. Something is going on here. Check the Makefile generated by configure. Maybe CFLAGS is getting overwritten there. Or maybe you can run make with `CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 make` in one line.

Comment: Yep, I notice that too. In the Makefile, the CFLAGS setting is empty. I tried adding -m32 in the Makefile, saving it, and then running make, but it errors out with `./include/ruby/ruby.h:108: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_long’ is negative
./include/ruby/ruby.h:112: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_voidp’ is negative` which googling shows that it's some kind of 32/64bit incompatibility error.

I've successfully compiled ruby 1.8.7 to 32bit, so I think currently I'm going to stay with that. Now to get the mysql2 gem working... Thanks for your help.